# How to delete items by value from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

This is a very basic question, but I searched through the [official docs for list manipulation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RearrangingAndRestructuringLists.html) and [on the site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=delete+list+element+by+value), and I wasn't able to find a specific function to delete item(s) by value from a list.

I'm currently using pattern substitution for that:

```
somelist := Flatten[{Range[-5,5],Range[-3,3]}]
somelist /. 0->Nothing
```

> ```
> {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
> ```

So, is pattern substitution the canonical way of deleting items by value, or will this hurt seasoned Mathematica users? What are the other solutions to delete items by value?

Comment: `DeleteCases[0]@somelist`? Extension: `DeleteCases[-2 | 0 | 2]@somelist`.

Comment: Nice @Michael! I've seen [DeleteCases](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) but I didn't understand it may be used for that. In your experience, is this more common than using `/.`?

Comment: `DeleteCases` is a common solution, as is its complementary function `Cases`.  `Select` and `Pick` can be used, too, to filter a list.  `Nothing` is relatively new to the language, so it won't appear in older code; however, it doesn't seem like a bad choice.  Each approach has its virtues, and which to use might depend on the case at hand.  For large packed arrays, this would be efficient for deleting `0`: `Pick[somelist, Unitize@somelist, 1]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations @Michael. This may eventually be useful for other people coming to Mathematica from another computer language. Would you consider posting that as an answer?

Comment: The way you remove zeros from your list is just fine.

Comment: @Michael: I've synthesized your comments in an answer below. I hope you're ok with that. Feel free to edit that answer if there is something you disagree with!

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I've been too busy to write up an answer.

Comment: `Nothing` unpacks arrays: ``Range[3] /. 1 -> Nothing // Developer`PackedArrayQ``. Therefore I strongly discourage to get into the habit of using it for large numerical data. In that case, usually three-argument version of `Pick` is the fastest because that allows you to use a packed array as second argument (unfortunately, Boolean arrays cannot be packed).

Comment: Ah, I forgot this obligatory link: [(3496)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496)

Comment: @Henrik, I tried the three-args `Pick` you've suggested, but with confusing results. This works:  `Pick[Range[5], Range[5], Except[0]]`.  But this doesn't work: `somelist = Flatten[{Range[-5,5],Range[-3,3]}] ;
Pick[somelist, somelist, Except[0]]`

Comment: `Pick` does not work with patterns. This is why it is faster. Try e.g., `Pick[Range[-5,5], Unitize[Range[-5,5]], 1]`

Comment: @Henrik, actually by digging into the [_possible issues_ section of the `Pick` doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html#1661137017), I came to that solution that _does_ work: `Pick[somelist, somelist, Except[0, _Integer]]`

Answer (score 2):

To synthesize what has been said in the comments to the question:

- Several options are available, some of them making use of relatively new features of Mathematica
- There isn't a strong consensus to decide if some solution is better style than the other

So in no particular order:

### Map to `Nothing`

> ```
> somelist /. 0->Nothing
> ```
>
> <sub>Suggested by myself in the question</sub>
>
> Works well, but [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) being a relatively new addition to the language this solution won't appear in older code
>
> In addition, [Henrik Schumacher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher) strongly discourage to get into the habit of using this solution large numerical data. The reason is *"`Nothing` [unpacks arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array)."*  Henrik continues by saying, for large numerical data *"usually the three-argument version of [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html?q=Pick) is the fastest because that allows you to use a packed array as the second argument (unfortunately, Boolean arrays cannot be packed)"*

### Using `Pick`

Removing *matching* items is actually the same thing a picking only *non matching* items.

However, due to the way pattern matching is implemented, using [`Pick` with `Except` can lead to surprising results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html#1661137017). Here is a working solution:

```
Pick[somelist, somelist, Except[0, _Integer]]
```

Other possible uses of `Pick` to remove items are:

```
Pick[somelist, #!= 0 & /@ somelist ]
Pick[somelist,UnequalTo[0] /@  somelist ]
Pick[somelist,EqualTo[0] /@  somelist , False]
```

### DeleteCases

> ```
> DeleteCases[0]@somelist
> DeleteCases[0|1|2]@somelist
> ```
>
> <sub>Suggested by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)</sub>
>
> [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) *"is a common solution, as is its complementary function [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html?q=Cases). [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) and [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html?q=Pick) can be used, too, to filter a list"*

### `Cases`

Based on Michael's suggestions above, I would add:

```
Cases[somelist, Except[0]]
```

### `Select`

```
Select[somelist, # != 0 &]
Select[somelist, UnequalTo[0]]
```